# Kotlin - Strange behavior when taking screenshots of view

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of the displayed activity.
In this case, the activity contains a webview (wvMainView).
The problem is, the main content of the screen (usually a chart), does not appear in the screenshot. The only time I get the full screenshot is when I have a table inside the webpage.

Here is the code for the screenshot:

```
var lMainActivityLayout: ConstraintLayout? = findViewById(R.id.lMainActivityLayout)

val bitmap = getScreenShotFromView(lMainActivityLayout!!)
// val bitmap = getScreenShotFromView(wvMainView!!)

if (bitmap != null){ saveMediaToStorage(bitmap) }


private fun getScreenShotFromView(v: View): Bitmap?
{
    Log.i("-","MainActivity > getScreenShotFromView")

    var screenshot: Bitmap? = null
    try
    {
        screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.measuredWidth, v.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(screenshot)
        v.draw(canvas)
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        Log.e("GFG", "Failed to capture screenshot because:" + e.message)
    }

    return screenshot
}

private fun saveMediaToStorage(bitmap: Bitmap)
{
    Log.i("-","MainActivity > saveMediaToStorage")

    val filename = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    var fos: OutputStream? = null

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        this.contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply 
            {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            }

            val imageUri: Uri? = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

            fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
        fos = FileOutputStream(image)
    }

    fos?.use 
    {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
        Toast.makeText(this , "Image saved to Gallery!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

As for the screenshot, take a look at the example below. When I run the app and take the screenshot, inside the gray area there is a bar chart that simple won't show up in the screenshot.

I tried taking a screenshot of the main layout as well as of the web view but with the same result.

[image]

The iOS version of the app works fine.
Any idea on what causes this strange behavior?
Maybe I should take the screenshot of the entire screen and not of a certain view (is this possible)?

And another small issue - the screenshot does no always appear in the Gallery app although I can find it using the Files app.

Comment: "Any idea on what causes this strange behavior?" -- not everything is going to get captured that way, particularly things that use `SurfaceView`. "Maybe I should take the screenshot of the entire screen and not of a certain view (is this possible)?" -- there are media projection APIs for this on Android 5.0+.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks again for the PDF. Made thinks clear for me. However, I ended up using ScreenShotty.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ScreenShotty for this - https://github.com/bolteu/screenshotty

Add this to build.graddle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
```

Here's the code, maybe it helps someone:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
{
    Log.i("","MainActivity > onActivityResult")

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    screenshotManager!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

fun getFullScreenshot()
{
    Log.i("","MainActivity > getFullScreenshot")

    val screenshotResult = screenshotManager!!.makeScreenshot()
    val subscription = screenshotResult.observe(
        onSuccess =
        {
            // Add a delay to prefent lag / crash on Android 5.0/5.1.
            // Not sure if this is the correct way but it works for me
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ editScreenshot(it) }, 1000)
        },
        onError =
        {
            Log.i("", "Screenshot failed!")
        }
    )
}

fun editScreenshot(screenshot: Screenshot)
{
    Log.i("","MainActivity > editScreenshot")

    val width: Int = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
    val height: Int = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels

    val bitmap = when (screenshot)
    {
        is ScreenshotBitmap -> screenshot.bitmap
    }

    // Multiple resolutions cases go here

    bitmap?.apply {
        cropRectangle(
            xOffset = 50,
            yOffset = 250,
            newWidth = width - 100,
            newHeight = height - 450
        )?.let { saveMediaToStorage(it) }
    }
}

fun saveMediaToStorage(bitmap: Bitmap)
{
    Log.i("","MainActivity > saveMediaToStorage")

    val screenshotFileName = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    var fos: OutputStream? = null

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        this.contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {

                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, screenshotFileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            }

            val imageUri: Uri? = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val image = File(imagesDir, screenshotFileName)
        fos = FileOutputStream(image)
    }

    fos?.use {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
        Toast.makeText(this , "Captured View and saved to Gallery" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```